# Tuning watchdog cpu usage

Tags: raspbian, cpu, watchdog

I've enabled the watchdog module

```bsh
# /etc/modules

i2c-dev
bcm2835_wdt
```

And installed and activated the watchdog daemon with the following configuration:

```bsh
# /etc/watchdog.conf

realtime = yes
priority = 1

watchdog-timeout = 15
watchdog-device = /dev/watchdog

max-load-1 = 24
max-load-5 = 18
max-load-15 = 12
```

In order to fine-tune `max-load-*` parameter I would like to monitor the same cpu usage the watchdog daemon is looking at. I've been warned that is not the same that the cpu usage programs like `htop` reports.

Which command is `watchdog` using?